# Dynamic inheritance from Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a **Photo**-Model that helps me achieve storing each image as a thumbnail aswell:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, default=default_image)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_2, editable=False, default=default_image_2)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now I have another Model, lets call it **User**, which **inherits** from **Photo**:

```
class User(Photo):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Now lets say there are **multiple** classes inheriting from Photo and depending on the inheriting class, I want to set another ***upload_path*** and ***default_image***. How Do I achieve that? Can I somehow use the constructor?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Speaking from experience, inheriting from models seems like a good idea but it generally isn't. If you want to query all models which inherit from `Photo` django will either be very inefficient or only provide you with the basemodel references (which you'll need to resolved 1 by 1). I urge you to reconsider inheritance and/or test thoroughly before continuing

Comment: Alternatively you can make the models `abstract = True`. This might be more what you are looking for. This won't allow you to query all `Photo`'s but it will allow you to re-use code between models

Comment: @Exelian Thank you very much. I forgot to add the `abstract = True`-Line in this post, I already used it. But I still dont know how to go on, could you help me further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the best way to handle your use-case is slightly different. You can pass a function to `upload_to`. This function will be provided the signature `instance` and `filename` of the uploaded file [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

You can check class of the instance with `isinstance` or something similar and change the output accordingly.

```
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    if isinstance(instance, User):
        return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
    return 'photo/{1}'.format(filename)
```

Doing the same for `default` is a little bit harder. The `default` function won't be passed any reference to the model or field which will make it harder to override it based on model. You could simply add an `image` field to each of the concrete models, but I don't know if that would be appropriate.

Comment: While implementing your solution, I stumbled upon another problem. In the `upload_path()`-method I want to see which class called or inherited from `PhotoModel`. Do you know, how I get this information?